# php regex preg_match_all issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to figure out a problem I'm having with regex.

I'm using this regex with preg_match_all on a large multi line string:

```
 /(\{(if|while|function|loop|\$|#)(.+)\})/
```

It currently works to match all text that starts with { and ends with } such as {$test} or {$function="test()"}

However, if one line in the string contains two matching blocks, the regex returns the whole line such as:

{$value.url}" class="link">{$value.title}

I can't figure out how to make the regex not do a 'greedy' match with (.+). The reason why I have (.+) is because there could be any character/number/underscore/period/quote/space in between the two brackets {}.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Is this also validating or supporting nesting, what should happen if the string was `{if {$fish} do }`

Comment: That is a good question, however we are using a templating engine that doesn't use nested {}, your example would be {if="$fish"}This is a {$fish}{/if}. We just needed a quick request to scan all our files to find out which files had the if/while/etc statements in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `.+` ungreedy by adding a question mark like this `.+?`

Answer (score 1):

Try matching for everything except for the } and then the }.

`/(\{(if|while|function|loop|\$|#)([^\}]+)\})/`

Comment: That would break nesting (eg. {if {fish} do} would return {if {fish}

Comment: I think any non-greedy match will break nesting. I would have to imagine at that point that simple regex wouldn't cut it and it would move into full token parser type stuff. But I could be wrong.

Comment: True, but you could require no open brace instead so `[^\{\}]` which would then at least match a balanced pair on the inner nest